# Positional Argument missing "status"

Tags: django, python-3.6

In Django:

```
re_path(r'^accept_friend_request(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/$', accept_friend_request, name = 'accept_friend_request')
```

How do I add status as parameter in `url` pattern of string in template as well as in `re_path`?

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'accept_friend_request' uidb64=uid %}">Accept</a>
```

Here's the code I used:

```
def accept_friend_request(request, uidb64, status):
    """Accept button will lead to entry in database as accepted and reject button will lead to entry in database as rejected  based on status flag"""
    uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
    friend_user = User.objects.get(pk=Friend.to_user.id)
    f = Friend.objects.filter(friend_id=friend_user)
    if f:
       f.status = status
       f.save()
       return request, "users/friend_list.html", {"uid": uidb64, "status": status}`
    else:
       return render(request, 'blog/base.html')
```

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: We might need to see more of your program than this. Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# your url should include status

re_path(r'^accept_friend_request(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<status>[\w-]+)/$', accept_friend_request, name = 'accept_friend_request')
```